# Evaluation of class returns false

Tags: python, class, shapely

I have written this class:

```
class DSMCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, footprint):
        if footprint.__class__.__base__.__module__ is not 'shapely.geometry.base':
            raise TypeError('footprint input geometry is not a shapely geometry based object')
        self.footprint = footprint
```

As best as I can tell I need to do the whole business of `__class__.__base__.__module__` because I am trying to be inclusive of all shapely objects (`shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` and `shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon`, for example) and that combination of attributes was I found that seemed like it would work, since all the objects that I want to include output `shapely.geometry.base`.

When I run the code, however, I get a TypeError even when putting in a valid `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` object.  I have tried the above code with `shapely.geometry.base` both as a string and a module.  How can this be?

Some example objects to reproduce the error:

```
valid_geojson_polygon_feature = {
'properties': {"name":"test"},
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
    'coordinates': [[(-122.4103173469268, 37.78337247419125), (-122.41042064203376, 37.7833590750075),
                     (-122.41046641056752, 37.78360478527359), (-122.41047393562782, 37.783644775039576),
                     (-122.4103759761863, 37.78365638609612), (-122.4103173469268, 37.78337247419125)]],
    'type': 'Polygon'}}

from shapely.geometry import shape as get_shape
valid_shapely_polygon_feature = get_shape(valid_geojson_polygon_feature['geometry'])
print(valid_shapely_polygon_feature.__class__.__base__.__module__)
DSMCalc(valid_shapely_polygon_feature)
```

Comment: FYI, I just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595586/364696); string based testing in general is a bad idea (and will be wrong in reasonable cases), so I gave the correct, Pythonic approach using `isinstance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rely on `is` working with string literals. Even when it works, it's an implementation detail of CPython, and in this case, even CPython's implementation doesn't support it, because CPython only automatically interns string literals that fit the rules for identifiers (that is, variable names). Your string contains `.`s, which means it's not automatically interned. You can see this easily at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> x = 'shapely.geometry.base'  # Not a legal variable name
>>> y = 'shapely.geometry.base'
>>> x is y
False
>>> x = 'abc123'  # Legal variable name
>>> y = 'abc123'
>>> x is y
True
```

Basically, change your test to `!= 'shapely.geometry.base'`, and if you need more details, read up on [the difference between `is` and `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/364696).

I'll note that your test is flawed in other ways. Right now, you require the immediate parent to be defined in `shapely.geometry.base`. But if you subclass a valid class, the child will be invalid (because the `__base__` will refer to the subclass from the other module, not ultimate base class in `shapely.geometry.base`). A better solution is proper `isinstance` checking based on known good base classes, e.g.:

```
# Top of file
from shapely.geometry.base import BaseGeometry, GeometrySequence

# Test code (passing a tuple of legal bases classes is allowed)
if not isinstance(footprint, (BaseGeometry, GeometrySequence)):
    raise TypeError('footprint input geometry is not a shapely geometry based object')
```

which, on top of being more explicit about what you want (explicitly enumerating legal base classes), and allowing indirect subclasses of the classes in question rather than only direct subclasses of a handful of base classes from that module, avoids allowing spurious types like `CAP_STYLE` and `JOIN_STYLE` (which, while defined in `shapely.geometry.base`, appear to exist largely as simple enum-like classes of constants, not actual geometry related things, and are likely not types you'd want to allow).